# How to load image in website before anything else loads?

Tags: jquery, ajax, gif

I'm trying to load a .gif image on my website before anything else loads.

I've read that this is possible with jQuery but unfortunately all the methods that I have tried are not working. I have used onReadyfunction() and on (window).load as well but nothing seems to work.

P.S : I want to load the gif image before anything else loads so that the user can view the image before anything else and then after a few seconds when the site has been fully loaded in the background the gif image should disappear.

This is the code that i have tried :

```
<script> 
    $(window).load(function(){ 
        $('#dvLoading').fadeOut(7000); 
    }); 
</script> 

<div id="dvLoading"></div>
```

Add in the css i have used this :

```
#dvLoading { 
    background:url(img/image.jpg); 
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
    left: 0; 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    z-index: 9999; 
}
```

Comment: So what have you tried? Some code would be nice

Comment: This is the code that i have tried :

 <script>

 $(window).load(function(){

    $('#dvLoading').fadeOut(7000);

});

</script>

<div id="dvLoading"></div>

Comment: Add in the css i have used this : 

#dvLoading {
    background:url(img/image.jpg);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
}

Comment: Have also tried onReadyfunction() instead of $(window).load but still no good.

Comment: I am still experiencing a delay of 1 sec still due to which i can see my website for 1 sec and then the gif image loads and fades out after 7 seconds.

what i really want is to finish that delay of 1 sec so that the website can render in background easily as long as the user is viewing at the gif image.